# PIP Configuration file could not be loaded - File contains no section headers

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Python 3.8.2 and Windows 10 on my computer. Whenever I use any command with pip like "pip --version" I get the following error message:

Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini', line: 1

This path doesn't even exist on my computer. This happens regardless of the (virtual) environment I'm in. I've searched for quite a while now and couldn't a solution find this specific problem. I'm fairly new to programming, so it's entirely possible that I'm doing something obvious wrong. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered almost the same problem. But there is a pip.ini in that path on my computer, and the problem was solved after I deleted it. Maybe this can provide you with a little information.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my file was stored in a RTF format, had to make it plain text and then it worked!